# Django: Truncate text given the width of parent div

Tags: python, django, truncate

I'm looking to achieve an effect using Django where the text will truncate (i.e. put ... at the end) when the length of the text exceeds that of the parent div.
With Django, the template tag allows me to set a fixed number of characters at which the text will truncate

```
{{ user.email|truncatechars:24 }}
```

However, I'm looking for a more dynamic solution. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing this [with css?](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Comment: @JensAstrup This doesn't work for me as the parent divs width is specified in % and not in px.